# How use collection with pageviewcontroller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, pagination, uicollectionview

I'm working on app where i need to display the images dynamically from server in horizontal scrolling fashion with pagination and user can select perticular image also does anybody have any idea? i have attached image for the same [image]

Comment: user3306145 I have sample code for this.I tried for someone asked related to your question in stackoverflow.I got the output.

Comment: user3182143 Can you please reply your answer here?

Comment: I created simple collection view with 7 images.Now If I click that it shows the image in next view controller.Then if I swipe it shows the next images.

Answer (score 0):

You need a view controller with a collection view child controller and an image view.   Implement a custom initialiser for your collection view, e.g.,

```
// Custom initializer for the CV controller.   Diameter is the 
// diameter of the round photo.
- (id)initWithPhotoDiameter:(CGFloat)diameter
{
    // Configure the layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter*1.50f);  // Allow some vertical space for the label
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8.0f;

    // Init the collection view
    self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    if (self) {
        _photoDiameter = diameter;
    }

    return self;
}
```

The `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath` would have code that changes the transparency of the round photo and changes the image on the image view to match the round photo.  This code would ideally (but not strictly) be in the delegate, which in this case would be the collection view controller's parent view controller.

Comment: Thanks will try it.